# C++ Using enumeration for flags and bitwise operations, easily

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, enums

In C I am able to take two or more enumerated flags and inclusive OR them: `(flag1 | flag2)`

In C++ I cannot do the same thing. I have some flags that I've scoped to my class but to OR them I have to cast. It looks like this:

```
namespace name
{
    class test
    {
    public:
        enum flag
        {
            firstflag = 1, secondflag = 2, thirdflag = 4
        };

        void foo(flag flags)
        {
            return;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    name::test obj;

    obj.foo((name::test::flag)(name::test::firstflag | name::test::secondflag));

    return 0;
}
```

That's kind of a mouthful, more in the real code than this example. I am wondering if there is a better way. I could change the argument passed to int `void foo(int flags)` but then in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger I wouldn't see the flags ORed, just a number.

Without the cast I get an error:

```
obj.foo(name::test::firstflag | name::test::secondflag);
error C2664: 'name::test::foo' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'name::test::flag'
```

I searched on stackoverflow and found a question with the answer to overload the `|` operator:
[c++ - "enum - invalid conversion from int" in class - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337064/enum-invalid-conversion-from-int-in-class)

Yet when I use `std::ios` flags I don't have to do any casting, why is that? For example fstream has a prototype like for example `fstream(char *filename, std::ios_base)` and I can do this in my code:

```
fstream("filename",  ios::in | ios::out);
```

What do you guys suggest? I do not have a lot of C++11 capabilities so if you could keep that in mind when answering. Thanks

Comment: Looking at `std::ios_base`, the flags are declared `static constexpr type variable = implementation`

Comment: Aside from your question, the mouthful is easily slightly shortened: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9898f77f95c3c8b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the GCC implementation of ios::in, ios::out, etc. They use operator overloading to get the desired effect. E.g.

```
inline _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR _Ios_Openmode
operator|(_Ios_Openmode __a, _Ios_Openmode __b)
{ return _Ios_Openmode(static_cast<int>(__a) | static_cast<int>(__b)); }
```

In your case you could define the following method:

```
inline flag operator|(flag f1, flag f2)
{ 
  return flag(static_cast<int>(f1) | static_cast<int>(f2)); 
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: This actually answers the question!  +1

Comment: Does static_cast really make a difference here? I'm surprised to see that because in visual studio they use (int)

Answer (score 1):

`std::bitset` is pretty good style for C++.  [Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)

```
#include <bitset>

namespace Flags {
enum Flags {
  first, second, third, NUM_FLAGS
};
}

class Test {
public:
  void foo(std::bitset<Flags::NUM_FLAGS> flags) {
    return;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::bitset<Flags::NUM_FLAGS> flags;
  flags[Flags::first] = true;
  flags[Flags::second] = false;
  flags[Flags::third] = true;

  Test obj;
  obj.foo(flags);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a template class to convert flags to `std::bitset<>` (which doesn't need [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) indices and vice versa:

```
template<typename BitFieldType, BitFieldType BitValue, int8_t CurIndex>
struct BitIndexSelector;

template<typename BitFieldType, BitFieldType BitValue, int8_t CurIndex>
struct BitIndexSelector
{
    static const int8_t ResultIndex =
            ((CurIndex != -1) &&
             (((((BitFieldType)1) << CurIndex) & BitValue) > 0)
            ? CurIndex
            : BitIndexSelector
                <BitFieldType
                ,BitValue
                ,CurIndex - 1>::ResultIndex);

};

template<typename BitFieldType, BitFieldType BitValue>
struct BitIndexSelector<BitFieldType,BitValue,-1>
{
    static const int8_t ResultIndex = -1;
};
```

---

```
template<typename BitFieldType, BitFieldType BitValue = 0>
struct GetBitIndex
{
    static const int8_t Index =
        BitIndexSelector
            < BitFieldType
            , BitValue
            , sizeof(BitFieldType) * sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT>::ResultIndex;
    typedef std::bitset<sizeof(BitFieldType) * CHAR_BIT> BitsetType;
};
```

Here's a sample for usage to convert the bitmask defined `poll()` event types to index values for accessing the various flags represented with a `std::bitset<>` in a convenient way:

```
enum PollEvents
{
    EV_POLLIN = GetBitIndex<short,POLLIN>::Index ,
    EV_POLLOUT = GetBitIndex<short,POLLOUT>::Index ,
    EV_POLLPRI = GetBitIndex<short,POLLPRI>::Index ,
    EV_POLLRDHUP = GetBitIndex<short,POLLRDHUP>::Index ,
    EV_POLLERR = GetBitIndex<short,POLLERR>::Index ,
    EV_POLLHUP = GetBitIndex<short,POLLHUP>::Index ,
};
```

A corresponding `std::bitset<>` can be manipulated using the indices defined in the enum above:

```
GetBitIndex<short>::BitsetType pollEventMask;

pollEvents[EV_POLLIN] = true; // set the POLLIN flag
pollEvents[EV_POLLERR] = false; // unset the POLLERR flag
```

The two operations above will do the same as:

```
short pollEventMask= POLLHUP | POLLERR; // Initialization just to show preset 
                                        // values
pollEventMask = (pollEventMask | POLLIN) & ~POLLERR; // This is the equivalent
                                                     // for the operations shown
                                                     // above
```

Some people claim for shortness, I personally claim for easy to read and use code on the semantics level (as long it doesn't hurt performance or footprint significantly).

A complete code sample can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/makulik/7963331) (note it's only a gist I made, to bring it into productive state in another project).

Comment: That appears to be _complete_ overkill

Comment: @MooingDuck I have found that pretty useful for some contexts. I'm pretty sure that using a `std::bitset<>` to manage a certain set of flags is in no way more inefficient, than manipulating these directly with the `|`, `&` and `~` operators.

Comment: There is the fact that it's built in and everyone ought to know about it.  To justify a custom version, you'd have to demonstrate that yours is significantly better in some way.  I an't even figure out what yours _does_ much less why it's better.

Comment: @MooingDuck I edited to clarify a bit (ha pun intended ;) ). If one doesn't need such translation, just to define the bitset indices as enum is the more reasonable solution of course (as shown in Sam Cristall's answer).