# C++ How to give a parameter a specific enumeration it can be?

Tags: c++, parameters, enumeration

How do I give a parameter a list of values it is allowed to be passed as? Here is an example function:

```
void GamePiece::Rotate(int z){
    int x, y;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        x = pieceRectangles_[i].getPosition().y * z;
        y = pieceRectangles_[i].getPosition().x;
    }
}
```

I want z to be either 1 or negative 1. Besides if statements, how do I ensure this?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: If you want compile time verification, use two functions (RotatePositive, RotateNegative) - You might wrap that in a template

Answer (score 3):

You can use an actual `enum class` instead of passing the value by `int`.

```
enum class ERotation { eCW = 1, eCCW = -1 };
```

Then your function would be

```
void GamePiece::Rotate(ERotation const& z){
    // ...
}
```

Note though, if you use a `enum` like this, you cannot multiply `z` by your positions, because there is no implicit conversion to int. So you'd have to say

```
const int rotation = (z == ERotation::eCW) ? 1 : -1;
```

Or as @rici mentioned you can explicitly cast the `enum` value

```
const int rotation = int(z);
```

Using `enum class` is [typesafe](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) and will not allow a value outside the enumeration to be passed. This is also more extensible than `bool` since you can have many values, instead of two.

Comment: You can explicitly cast to int. Also, the enum is typesafe but not exactly value-safe since you can explicitly cast from int, as well. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10a04b2baef64a3e

Comment: @rici I didn't know that. That's definitely interesting. Any idea why they allow you to do `Rotation(42)` if that's not one of the enumerated values?

Comment: I found a thorough discussion of [that topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/what-happens-if-you-static-cast-invalid-value-to-enum-class)

Comment: @Cyber: the compiler can't - in general - know what the intended enumeration values are, as enums have often been used (albeit more so in C APIs) as values to be combined and tested using e.g. bitwise operations.  Still, in C++03 there's a formula for finding the Standard-guaranteed min and max values the enum can store, so it's not necessarily just "any int", while in C++11 you can optionally specify a particular underlying integral type which affects the values that can be stored.

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean instead of `int`:

```
void GamePiece::Rotate(bool positive){
    int x, y;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        x = pieceRectangles_[i].getPosition().y * ( positive ? 1 : -1 );
        y = pieceRectangles_[i].getPosition().x;
    }
}
```

You probably should call that parameter something like clockwise, but I do not know if clockwise is +1 or -1 in your system.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me you are doing a 90′ degree rotation in 2D around a virtual normal (axis) in a positive or negative Z direction:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x, int y)
    :   x(x), y(y)
    {}
};

struct VirtualNormalZ
{
    int value;
    VirtualNormalZ(int value)
    :   value(0 <= value ? 1 : -1)
    {}
};

// CCW is positive
Point Rotate90Degrees(const Point p, const VirtualNormalZ& normal)
{
    return Point(p.y * -normal.value, p.x * normal.value);
}

int main()
{
    VirtualNormalZ positive_normal(123);
    Point p(1, 0);
    std::cout << "Positive:\n";
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << p.x << ", " << p.y << '\n';
        p = Rotate90Degrees(p, positive_normal);
    }
    VirtualNormalZ negative_normal(-123);
    std::cout << "Negative:\n";
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << p.x << ", " << p.y << '\n';
        p = Rotate90Degrees(p, negative_normal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ask for a boolean or an enumerator instead, and translate this to 1 or -1 when you need it.