# constructing enum with underlying "bool" type from a boolean?

Tags: c++, enums

If I define an enum like so:

```
enum Foo : bool { Left = false, Right = true };
```

then try to construct one from a boolean like so:

```
int main (int ac, const char **av) {
    Foo foo ( ac > 1 );
    cout << boolalpha << bool(foo) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it fails, but works with an extra constructor like so:

```
Foo foo ( Foo( ac > 1 ) );
```

Why is this? I thought `Foo foo (...)` *was* an explicit constructor call?

Comment: (orthogonal) Suggestion: use `enum class Foo` and `static_cast<Foo>()`.

Comment: In `Foo foo( Foo( ac > 1 ) )`, the second `Foo` is in fact a cast.

Comment: I guess  `Foo( ac > 1 ) ` is typecasting result of `(ac > 1)` to `Foo`.  And `Foo foo ( Foo( ac > 1 ) );`  involves calling byfefault copy constructor of `Foo`.

Comment: I guess that answers the question :) thankyou both (and thankyou for the suggestion, although I prefer constructor syntax for the conversion; I guess actually I *would* like the conversion to be implicit).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting integral type to enum: functional cast vs initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070130/converting-integral-type-to-enum-functional-cast-vs-initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foo foo ( ac > 1 );
That's a case of the C++ [most vexing parse](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/01/30/most-vexing-parse/).  It's a function declaration that does nothing.

Comment: How can the comparison `(ac > 1)` be interpreted as part (probably *argument*) of a function declaration?

Comment: Read the linked article about the C++ Most Vexing Parse!

Comment: yes, it doesn't say anything about how `(ac > 1)` would be parsed as function argument type. That's why I asked.

Comment: Reizo is right: this is not a most vexing parse case because `ac > 1` cannot be parsed as a function argument, so it has to be parsed as an expression (and therefore the whole declaration is parsed as an initializer rather than a function declaration).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this:

```
Foo foo ( ac > 1 );
```

Suppose you define Foo enum as:

```
enum Foo : bool { Left = false };
```

What would happen if you called:

```
Foo foo(true);
```

You don't have appropriate enum value for what you want to initialize with.

Comment: That's not really answering the question *per se*, although it's a valid caveat to casting involving `enum`s in most cases.

Comment: This is incorrect. As long as the value is representable by the underlying type of the enum (in this case `bool`) it can be cast to the enum type, even if it isn't explicitly enumerated (See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195312)