# Why does casting an int to a strongly typed enum compile if it is "not within the enums range"?

Tags: c++, enums, casting, compiler-errors

In the code below, I use `static_cast` to convert an strongly typed `enum` to an `int`. The same works in the other direction. But it also works if the cast `int` is not within the range of the `enum`. Why is that and why is the compiler not catching this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum class Name {Hans, Peter, Georg}; // 0, 1, 2

std::string getName(Name name) {
    switch(name) {
        case Name::Hans:  return "Hans";
        case Name::Peter: return "Peter";
        case Name::Georg: return "Georg";
        default: return "not valid name";
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Cast a Name to an int, works fine.
    std::cout<< static_cast<int>( Name::Peter ) <<std::endl; // 1
    std::cout<< static_cast<int>( Name::Hans ) <<std::endl;  // 0

    // Cast an int to a Name
    std::cout<< getName(static_cast<Name>(2)) <<std::endl;   // Georg
    std::cout<< getName(static_cast<Name>(3)) <<std::endl;   // not a valid name
    // I would expect a compiler error/warning like i get here:
    // std::cout<< static_cast<int>( Name::Hans + 4 ) <<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: On what basis do you think the compiler should "catch" this? As far as I know the C++ standard doesn't require any diagnostics for this.

Comment: Adding checks for validity of the integer value will impose a runtime overhead.

Comment: The error I get when I uncomment that last line is `no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘Name’ and ‘int’)` which doesn't have anything to do with your question about enum range.

Comment: I would expect that it is possible to pick this up, though, both clang and gcc don't emit a warning for this. As you are using `static_cast`, you already already telling the compiler: I know better!

Comment: To cast means to overwriting the type system by providing additional information that it (the type system) can't or isn't allowed to deduce itself. The compiler will implicitly trust that this information is accurate, regardless of how implausible it is. Casts overwrite a safety system, they are not implicitly safe, the burden falls on the developer to use them correctly.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, people often use enums to represent bit flags:

```
enum class FontFlags { bright=0x1, bold=0x2, blink=0x4 };
```

Now they expect this to work:

```
FontFlags(int(FontFlags::bold) | int(FontFlags::blink))
```

But of course the value is 6 which is "impossible."

Comment: Strongly typed enums (with `enum class`) do not support `operator|`.

Comment: @Kevin: Updated to address that.

Comment: I think that kind of defeats the purpose of this answer though. If you need to convert to an `int` before you can get an "impossible" value for the enum then you no longer have a valid enum.

Comment: @Kevin: I'm trying to demonstrate why the compiler should not just reject construction or casting of enums from ints that aren't mapped.  Whether I type `6` or `bold|blink` doesn't really matter - the value is the same, and it needs to be valid or people's code will break.

Comment: @John Are you sure the standard mandates `6` to be valid when casted to `FontFlags`? I thought it is undefined behaviour to cast an unlisted value to the enum class.

Comment: @Bernard: It's only UB if the value is outside the range of the `underlying_type` of the enum.  So 6 does not lead to UB.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/what-happens-if-you-static-cast-invalid-value-to-enum-class