# expected initializer before '&' token in enumarator operator overloading C++

Tags: c++

I want to write overloading operator, that increments `enum` type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;


enum Type {grun,grun_blinkend,gelb,rot ,rot_gelb,gelb_blinkend}



Type& operator++(Type& color){
    return color = static_cast<Type>(++static_cast<int>(Type)); 
};
```

But it throws me an error:

error: expected initializer before '&' token

Why and how can I fix it?

I need this operator in order to iterate over the Type for "traffic light" simulation:

```
Ampel Ampel::weiter(){
    if(zustand ==  Type(rot_gelb)){
        zustand = Type(grun);
        return Ampel(zustand);
    }
    ++zustand;
    return Ampel(zustand);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it might also be useful to explain the rationale behind this operator? There might be a whole different solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis edited

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after the enum definition. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: What if the value of `color` is `gelb_blinkend`? What happens then when you "increase" it? What will `color` then be?

Comment: @molbdnilo What about some of the other errors? The increment requires an lvalue and the argument of the cast is a type and not an identifier.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis Those are unrelated to the error message in question.

Comment: To clarify: without the semicolon, the compiler sees `enum Type { ... } Type ...` and expects the variable `Type` (which has the type `Type`) to have an initializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution, but you must be cautious about an integer higher to gelb_blinkend, for a good explanation about that I recommend see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195312/what-happens-if-you-static-cast-invalid-value-to-enum-class) and also you should think about change `enum` for `enum class`, for this I suggest this  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum).

```
enum Type {grun,grun_blinkend,gelb,rot ,rot_gelb,gelb_blinkend};

Type& operator++(Type& color){
    int current = static_cast<int>(color);
    return color = static_cast<Type>(++current); 
};
```