# GCC warnings for user types using QVariant::Type in a switch block

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

Basically we're keeping the track of object types in a variable of QVariant::Type and then doing something like that

```
switch(values[i].type)
{
case QVariant::Bool: logic; break;
case QVariant::Int: logic; break;
case QVariant::LongLong: logic; break;
case QVariant::String:  logic; break;
case QVariant::Double:  logic; break;
case QVariant::DateTime:
case QVariant::Date:
case QVariant::Time:   logic; break;
case QVariant::User+1:
{
    logic;break;
}
case QVariant::User+2:
{
    logic;break;
}
default: break;
}
```

The problem is: gcc produces warnings along these lines for User+X statements:

```
 warning: case value ‘1025’ not in enumerated type ‘QVariant::Type’ [-Wswitch]
```

Now, I could suppress that of course, but is that the recommended way or am I doing something fundamentally wrong here?

P.S. The question isn't about *why* the warning is produced: I understand why. The queston is more about using QVariant::Type with user types in a proper way and if simply suppressing is correct or what am I doing here is just plain wrong and warning is an indication of a bigger design decision problem.

Comment: Maybe you are compiling with the `-Wswitch-enum` flag?

Comment: I am compiling with -Wall -Wextra. So, you recomment I just suppress if I want to keep these (otherwise relevant) warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`QVariant::type enum`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Type-enum):

```
QMetaType::User 1024    Base value for user types
```

this is like:

```
switch(1024) {
   ...
   case (1024 + 1): break;
   default: break;
}
```

the governing rule in switch for `enum` is to be **explicit**.

`(1024 + 1)` is not explicit thus the warning.

**UPDATE**

As per [qvariant.html#type](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#type)

> Returns the storage type of the value stored in the variant. Although
>   this function is declared as returning QVariant::Type, the return
>   value should be interpreted as QMetaType::Type. In particular,
>   `QVariant::UserType` is returned here **only if** the value is equal or
>   greater than QMetaType::User.

Thus, `QVariant::UserType + 1` will be dead code.

Time to [**refactor**](https://towardsdatascience.com/refactoring-is-the-cure-for-technical-debt-but-only-if-you-take-it-9fd8cc42dd93)

Comment: Wait what? First of all: where did switch(1024) come from? your answer doesnt make any sense to me

Comment: I think the point is that each enumerator is just a name for a number in an `int` (or other underlying type). And Qt never declared any enumerator for `User + 1` (for obvious reasons), but the compiler doesn't know this is OK. I don't see that translating the code to use `int`s really helps though.

Comment: Your answer would make sense if there was not default: break; but it is there so by your logic, there is a conditional branch for every possible case

Comment: Anyway, your answer deals with why the warnign is emitted, please read the P.S. of the question for what the real question is here.

Comment: @Zeks, updated my answer. also to make things simpler, `UserType + 1` will be dead code. The warning is there since `UserType + 1` is **not** explicit. It's not part of the `enum`. compiler knows the type of `values[i].type`.

Comment: I am sorry to report that you are completely wrong. I just ran a debug on that code and QVariant::User+1 branch is entered correctly. It is most certainly not a dead branch. This code has been working for a couple years and if there was a problem with dead branches it would have been noticed. And actual real life debug proved it is alive

Comment: @Zeks, then you should be worried. you're not following the standards.

Comment: @Zeks, Also the probable cause would be `User + 1` is a "special" case for your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by special case

Comment: @Zeks, it means "how on earth does the program get 1025 if QT doesn't support that value for `types`"

Comment: Possibly. Seems like my hunch was correct and the whole using QVariant::Type needs to go away, not the warning. Been ignoring it for way too long.

Comment: @Zeks, [refactor now before it's too late](https://towardsdatascience.com/refactoring-is-the-cure-for-technical-debt-but-only-if-you-take-it-9fd8cc42dd93)

Comment: Agreed. Once the current deadline passes here, I am refactoring this part into something sensible.

Comment: Reporting in: refactoring this stuff did, indeed, break it in a major way :) Thankfully I caught it before it went to production. But  I was right to be reluctant

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use user types in the QVariant, you should use the member function [userType](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#userType):

Unfortunately, this will make things uglier:

```
auto u = [](auto& v){return static_cast<int>(v);};
switch(values[i].userType())
{
case u(QVariant::Bool): logic; break;
case u(QVariant::Int): logic; break;
case u(QVariant::LongLong): logic; break;
case u(QVariant::String):  logic; break;
case u(QVariant::Double):  logic; break;
case u(QVariant::DateTime):
case u(QVariant::Date):
case u(QVariant::Time):   logic; break;
case u(QVariant::User)+1:
{
    logic;break;
}
case u(QVariant::User)+2:
{
    logic;break;
}
default: break;
}
```

To clarify: Note that the `type()` member function will always return `QVariant::UserType` when the type value is greater than `QMetaType::User`. This means it will never return `QVariant::UserType+n`! How could it? Those values are not part of the enumeration.

This is what gcc is warning you about:

```
warning: case value ‘1025’ not in enumerated type ‘QVariant::Type’ [-Wswitch]
```

Since `1025`(`QVariant::User+1`) is not part of `QVariant::Type`, this case label is essentially dead code.

The `userType` member function, however, returns `int`. It will return the same underlying value as `type` when that value is below `QMetaType::User`, and also the correct user value when above.

Comment: values[i] is not a QVariant. The type is explicitly stored outside. I am starting to suspect I need to use an external enum for that that is not a Qt enum.

Comment: @Zeks If you are storing values outside of the range of the enum in a data member, the behavior is unspecified (prior to C++17) or **undefined** (After C++17). This means your case labels are subject to being optimized away (or worse). As you already realized, to solve this, you either: Use the underlying type instead; or, use a separate enum with all the values you need defined.

Comment: (More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195408/3854787))

Comment: Thanks. I seem to need to refactor that part before its too late.