# static_cast to enum class from underlying type value and switch for compiler assistance

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Suppose I have an enum:

```cpp
enum class Thing : std::uint8_t {
  Foo = 21,
  Bar = 42,
  Baz = 1
};
```

I want to convert a "raw" value (of the underlying type) to a value of that enum, with error handling catching values which are not "a thing".  I could use checks like `if (raw_value == static_cast<std::uint8_t>(Thing::Foo))` and then an `else` with the error handling, but then **I could forget** for example `Thing::Baz`.  However, when I switch over a value of type `Thing`, then my compiler (as probably most modern compilers) warns me about unhandled enumeration values ("enumeration value `Baz` not handled in switch").

So I came up with this:

```cpp
Thing thingFromUInt8(std::uint8_t const b) {
  Thing const t = static_cast<Thing>(b);
  switch (t) { // If I'd add Thing::Frob but forget it here I get a warning
    case Thing::Foo:
    case Thing::Bar:
    case Thing::Baz:
      return t;
  }
  throw std::runtime_error("That's not a thing...");
}
```

Questions:

- Is this "legal" C++ (C++11 and above)?
- If it is, does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: It is legal C++. It is a bit verbose, you need to write a lot, but leveraging the compiler warnings in the `switch` is a good idea. BTW, I think your question better belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It's *legal*, but if you're asking whether a warning (or some diagnostic) is guaranteed, I don't think it is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195408/1116364 This also answers the legality; adding here for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal C++.

The drawback is the DRY violation, but avoiding it is difficult.

In [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) we'll have reflection and be able to generate equivalent code (without having to rely on compiler warnings to make sure we didn't miss any).  Reflection syntax is still a bit in flux, but every version I have read over was able to handle that problem.

Comment: Thanks, looking very much forward to C++23 :)